# PlotlyJS fails to produce a plot in Julia

Tags: julia

I came across with an odd situation that I can't understand. Running Julia 1.7.3 under Ubuntu 22.04. I have one file.jl that contains the code below. The code in area1() produces a plot. But the code in bizarre() does not. I have tried this from xTerm and under VSC. In both cases area1() plots OK but bizarre() does not.

This is driving me crazy. Any help/suggestion greatly appreciated. Thank you

```
using DataFrames
using Statistics
using LinearAlgebra
using PlotlyJS

function area1()
  trace1 = scatter(;x=1:4, y=[0, 2, 3, 5], fill="tozeroy")
  trace2 = scatter(;x=1:4, y=[3, 5, 1, 7], fill="tonexty")
  plot([trace1, trace2])
end

function bizarre()
  println("Start Bizarre")
  trace1 = scatter(;x=1:4, y=[0, 2, 3, 5], fill="tozeroy")
  trace2 = scatter(;x=1:4, y=[3, 5, 1, 7], fill="tonexty")
  plot([trace1, trace2])
  println("End of Bizarre")
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The confusion stems from the fact that *`plot` is not a plotting function*. `plot` is a Plot-creation function i.e. it creates a `Plot` object with the data and characteristics you specify. It does not by itself create a figure on the screen. That is the job of the `display` function.

When you call `area1` from the REPL in xTerm (and whatever equivalent is used in VSCode), the REPL automatically calls `display` on the return value of the function. This is true for any function call, and is the "print" part of "read-eval-print-loop". And functions in Julia automatically return the value of the last expression they evaluate. So, in `area1`, since the `plot` call is on the last line, the resulting `Plot` object is returned, and then automatically `display`ed by the REPL.

In `bizarre`, the last statement is a `println`, which returns `nothing`, so nothing is printed or displayed. The statement before that, the `plot` call, just creates a `Plot` object, but doesn't `display` it, so it's just created and thrown away. If you replace that line with `display(plot([trace1, trace2]))`, you'll see that that function produces a plot too.